# Image.png not found

Tags: graphics

I have an error in latex:

`` Package pdftex.def Error: File `figures/bootstrap.png' not found: using draft ``

I have the image in the same folder as the `.tex` file, I closed and reopened the file, but it did not turn out. How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage[figurename=Figura]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/crisf/Documents/resumenlibros/}}


\begin{document}
\section{2013 - An introduction to statistical learning - with applications in R}

\subsection{Capítulo 2.¿Qué es aprendizaje estadístico?}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \includegraphics[width=11cm]{figures/bootstrap.png}
    \centering
    \caption{Conjuntos de datos distintos mediante el muestreo repetido de observaciones del conjunto de datos original.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The error, "File 'figures/bootstrap.png' not found" indicates it wants to find the figure in a subdirectory named `figures`.  This, of course, occurs because your code tells `\includegraphics` to find it there: `\includegraphics[width=11cm]{figures/bootstrap.png}`

Comment: Thank you! It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in the same file as the `.tex` file, you do not need the `\graphicspath` command. Simply removing it should remedy the problem. That command is only used if the files are not located in the same directory as the `.tex` file. Secondly, your `\includegraphics` command calls for an image located at `figures/bootstrap.png`. That would mean the image would be in a folder within the project folder with the name `figures`. It should read `\includegraphics[width=11cm]{bootstrap.png}` if the image is in the same folder as the `.tex` file, or you could leave the command as-is and move the image to a new folder within the project folder named `figures`.

Comment: Did you mean the same _file_ as the `.tex` file, or the same _folder_?